# How to apply linear-gradient on an input on its border-bottom only?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have this requirement:

If condition A is met then the border-bottom of my input element need to be a certain color. Same thing applies if condition B is met.

But if both condition A and B are met, I need to show both colors on the border-bottom of my input element.  I have tried using linear-gradient but I cannot make it work on the border-bottom of my input.

[Here's a Codepen example I created](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNXoNm)

```
 .condition-a {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #984B43 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-b {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #EAB226 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-a-b {
    /*border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #EAB226 !important;*/
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width of the other three borders explicitly to 0px. This is because there is a default `border: 2px inset` border for `input` elements (atleast in Chrome) and the `border-bottom` property overrides only the color of the bottom border and doesn't reset the width of the other borders.

```css
.condition-a {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #984B43 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-b {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #EAB226 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-a-b {
    /*border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #EAB226 !important;*/
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Condition A is met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-a" />
</p>
<p>
  Condition B is met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-b" />
</p>
<p>
  Condition A and B are both met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-a-b" />
</p>
```

---

Post your clarification in comments, I understand that you need the other borders to remain the same while only the bottom border has a gradient effect. Such an effect I don't think can be produced using `border-image` because the border image gets applied on all sides. But you could mimick this using a `background-image` like in the below snippet. (Note that this is only a workaround solution).

```css
.condition-a {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #984B43 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-b {
    border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
    border-bottom-color: #EAB226 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.condition-a-b {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #EAB226 50%, #984B43 50%);
    background-size: calc(100% + 4px) 2px; /* 4px extra to cater for 2px border on right + 2px on left */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box; /* make background start from border area itself instead of content/padding area */
    background-position: left bottom;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Condition A is met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-a" />
</p>
<p>
  Condition B is met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-b" />
</p>
<p>
  Condition A and B are both met:
  <input type="text" class="condition-a-b" />
</p>
```

Comment: Except, I need to see the outline of the other borders. Just like we see it with condition A or B

Comment: Ah, you should've made that explicit in the question. Let me try and see if there is a way for that @Microcontroleur

Comment: @Microcontroleur: What you are looking for is not achievable using `border-image` as far as I can see and so I've added a solution using `background-image` which produces the same visual output. It is only a workaround but it might most probably be your best bet for now.

Comment: awesome!  This exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.